# Does anyone know of a flash box control

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have been googeling  it for a while but with no success.
I am looking for a flash tutorial or maybe a control that implements the following (It's not very difficult but I am very new and if I try doing it myself it will turn quite ugly).

A box that is composed of subitems. each subitem can be viewed or removed from the box. I'd like drag and drop also but it's not that essential.

Nothing that difficult, maybe that's why I didn't find anything...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Yahoo Flash components](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/layout-containers/)? I'm not shure if this is exactly what you need.